# Show that that if $p,q,r,s$ are real numbers and $pr=2(q+s)$, then at least one of the eqns $x^2+px+q=0$ and $x^2+rx+s=0$ has real roots.

Tags: quadratics

Show that that if $p,q,r,s$ are real numbers and $pr=2(q+s)$, then at least one of the eqns $x^2+px+q=0$ and $x^2+rx+s=0$ has real roots.

My Attempt to the solution

we know to have a real solution d>=0 so either

1) $p^2-4q>=0$

or

2) $r^2-4s>=0$

or both are true.

Rearranging we get $(pr)^2 \geq 16qs$
substituting it in the first eqn we get
$16qs\geq4q^2 +4s^2 +8qs$
So we get $0\geq(q-s)^2$ so we get $q=s$. Now what to do..? is there any another way to solve this?

Comment: 1. You cannot multiply inequalities without considering the signs. 
2. Even if the inequality was correct, you  should've had $16qs\leq 4q^2 +\ldots$

Comment: If only one of the inequalities is guaranteed to be true, then you cannot combine them in any way.

Comment: Assume that neither equation has real roots and start from there. It's not hard to deduce that then $pr \neq 2(q+s)$.

Comment: Moreover, the logic is backwards... we want to show that one of those ineqs is true, not start assuming one or both are true.

Comment: Do as @DanielFischer said and consider the average of the discriminants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given: $pr = 2(q+s)$.  To prove: either $p^2 - 4q \geq 0$ or $r^2 - 4s \geq 0$.  It is best to argue by contradiction -- assume both $p^2 - 4q < 0$ and $r^2 - 4s < 0$.  Then upon rearranging and adding the inequalities,
$$  \begin{array}{rcl} p^2 + q^2 &<& 4r + 4s \\
  \frac{p^2 + q^2}{2} &<& 2(r + s)
  \end{array}
$$
Can you see how to finish from here?  If not, post a comment and I'll write more.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thnx. we will use am gm at the end..

Comment: There is a little correction in the above instead of $r$ the author wrote $q$. Given: $pr=2(q+s)$. To prove: either $p^2−4q≥0$ or $r^2−4s≥0$. It is best to argue by contradiction -- assume both $p^2−4q<0$ and $r^2−4s<0$. Then upon rearranging and adding the inequalities, $p^2+r^2 < 4q + 4s$ $\frac{p^2+r^2}{2} < 2(q + s)$ $\frac{p^2+r^2}{2} < pr$ $(pr=2(q + s))$ $(p^2+r^2) < 2pr$ $p^2 + r^2 - 2pr > 0$ $(p - r)^2 > 0$ it means $p = r$.

Comment: Thank you @VIPINSETIA, I'm sorry I didn't see that obvious typo before!